# Import swift class in kotlin native SharedCode iosMain module

Tags: android, objective-c, swift, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am using kotlin native and I have successfully integrated it in my project by using build.gradle.kts script from below link

https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/03_CreatingSharedCode

By using this I can call my kotlin class into ios app. But I am required to do reverse. I want to call swift classes written in ios app into my kotlin native ios module.

"A Swift library can be used in Kotlin code if its API is exported to Objective-C with @objc. Pure Swift modules are not yet supported." that I have came to know from below link.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html

For this purpose I believe cinterops {} should be used in build.gradle.kts file by passing header files created from swift class but don't know how to pass it.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to use swift classes that were pre-compiled as a framework, or these from your app code? The second option seems to be totally unattainable, as you compile the K/N framework before adding it to your Xcode project.

Comment: I am able to see swift classes of framework in kotlin native code. What I want is swift classes written by me in app code to be callable from kotlin native.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your use case, you can still call the Swift code from Kotlin/Native via a factory function.

My use case was that I needed to instantiate a custom UIView from the Kotlin code. I couldn't find a way to create a fully functional custom UIView in Kotlin directly, unfortunately. I got pretty far with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281270 , but hit a limit when I needed to overload updateConstraints() - which has to call super.updateConstraints() and I found no way how to do that via the Kotlin <-> Swift interop (and now I'm reasonably sure it's really not possible).

So instead, I have created the custom UIView in Swift:

```
class CustomView : UIView {

    ... init etc. ...

    override func updateConstraints() {
        ... my stuff ...
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

And implemented a factory function to instantiate it:

```
func customViewFactory(param: Param) -> UIView {
    return CustomView(param: param)
}
```

Then early during the app startup, I pass this factory function to the Kotlin/Native code like this:

```
KotlinClass.Companion.shared.setCustomViewFactory(factory: customViewFactory(param:))
```

In the Kotlin part of the project (that is actually compiled before the Swift part), it looks like this:

```
class KotlinClass {

    companion object {
        /* To be used where I want to instantiate the custom UIView from the Kotlin code. */
        lateinit var customViewFactory: (param: Param) -> UIView

        /* To be used early during the startup of the app from the Swift code. */
        fun setCustomViewFactory(factory: (param: Param) -> UIView) {
            customViewFactory = factory
        }
    }
```

When I want to instantiate the custom UIView in the Kotlin code, I just call:

```
val customView = customViewFactory(param)
```

And then can work with it as I need in the Kotlin part - add it to other view or anything...

Comment: This is the best approach, IMO. I originally tried writing Kotlin code against the imported cinterop (Swift Objective-C) bindings for frameworks like UIKit. But the Kotlin code ends up with contortions (like KotlinInt to NSNumber) to deal with APIs not designed for it. I am now going with having my iOS Swift code install functions into the Kotlin side while coding their platform specific implementations in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such option available at the moment. The main issue will be that the K/N code gets compiled before apps' swift classes compilation.
The most common situation of K/N usage in iOS apps follows this pipeline:

1. Compile Objective-C frameworks(or take a pre-compiled, e.g.
   system/third-party).
2. Write K/N code that uses those frameworks(through bindings generated by the `cinterop` tool).
3. Compile K/N to a framework or a library.
4. Use this framework/lib in your app.

I think the best you can do here is modularisation. If it's wanted to access some code written in Swift from Kotlin/Native, one should get this code into a separate project, compile it as a framework, write up a `cinterops{}` block for this framework, use the result bindings from Kotlin/Native, compile the framework and use it in your app. About modularising the code, the most illustrative example would be [this one](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/it-looks-like-youre-still-trying-to-use-a-framework/), it seems to be pretty straightforward.