# Kotlin Multiplatform /iOS: Gradient layer not showing in custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add a gradient view to a parent view, I subclassed a UIView and made changes following this [Subclassing UIView from Kotlin Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266205/subclassing-uiview-from-kotlin-native#)

Added a `uikit.def` file.

```
package = Custom_UIKit
language = Objective-C
---

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIView.h>

@protocol UIViewWithOverrides
- (void) layoutSubviews;
@end
```

This is MyView class:

```
import Custom_UIKit.UIViewWithOverridesProtocol
import kotlinx.cinterop.\*
import platform.CoreGraphics.\*
import platform.UIKit.\*
import platform.UIKit.UIColor
import platform.QuartzCore.CAGradientLayer

class MyView() : UIView(frame = CGRectMake(.0, .0, 0.0, 0.0)), UIViewWithOverridesProtocol {

    private val gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    init {
        setupGradient()
    }
    
    private fun setupGradient() {
        gradientLayer.colors = listOf(
            UIColor.redColor.CGColor,
            UIColor.blueColor.CGColor
        )
        gradientLayer.locations = listOf(0.0, 1.0)
        println("setupGradient")
        println(gradientLayer.frame.size)
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    
    override fun layoutSubviews() {
        println("layoutSubviews")
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        println(gradientLayer.frame.size)
    }

}
```

And this is how i am adding MyView:

```
val view = MyView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
displayContainer.getAdContainer()!!.addSubview(view)
view!!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(displayContainer.getAdContainer()!!.bottomAnchor).active = true
view!!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(displayContainer.getAdContainer()!!.leadingAnchor).active = true
view!!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(displayContainer.getAdContainer()!!.topAnchor).active = true
view!!.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(displayContainer.getAdContainer()!!.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

Please suggest a solution for adding a gradient layer to UIView in Kotlin Multiplatform or if something is wrong with this approach. Thank you!

Comment: as commend under that answer says, "You can't call super methods with this approach though. Might sometimes be desirable for layoutSubviews for example"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This was a nightmare to sort out, but I got it.

This is a complex problem in the iOS/Kotlin interop where Kotlin's interop stuff letting your colors get garbage collected too early.

After posting an incorrect explanation here, I posted my answer back to YouTrack and was corrected and pointed to this [other issue that has our exact usecase](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40429/CoreFoundation-types-dont-work-with-Kotlin-collections#focus=Comments-27-4292051.0-0).

Turns out it's much easier than I made it out to be.

```kotlin
gradientLayer.setColors(
    listOf(
        CFBridgingRelease(CFRetain(UIColor.redColor.CGColor)), 
        CFBridgingRelease(CFRetain(UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor))
    )
)
```